# Replacing input special characters with onChange

Tags: javascript, forms, input, onchange

I'm trying to replace this " with ׳׳ and also this ' with ׳ but it wont work.

```js
function replaceName(e) {
  e.value = e.value.replace(/'/g, '׳');
  e.value = e.value.replace(/"/g, "׳׳");
}
```

```html
<input class="form-control" name="name" type="text" onChange="replaceName(this)" />
```

Comment: Seems to work fine on my end.

Comment: working fine but with focus out you can also use onkeydown or onkeyup events for instant change after entering a word.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Better to use `oninput` than `onchange` if you want to see changes as user types. `onchange` is fired when `input` loses focus, `oninput` is fired for every input.

```js
function replaceName(e) {
  e.value = e.value.replace(/'/g, '׳');
  e.value = e.value.replace(/"/g, "׳׳");
}
```

```html
<input class="form-control" name="name" type="text" oninput="replaceName(this)" />
```

Comment: Also better to assign handlers with Javascript properly than with inline attributes